Amadeus Hotel Search using Enterprise Soap API return 17|Session|No agreement on destination
I'm trying to connect to Amadeus Enterprise Api Via Soap in ASP.NET Core but getting an error: 17|Session|No agreement on destination. Below is the codebase I'm using.
I have review the documentation over and over again but am not getting any headway
public async Task<string> SearchHotelsAsync(string latitude, string longitude)
{
    try
    {
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
        {
            Security = new BasicHttpSecurity
            {
                Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport  // Use Transport security for HTTPS
            }
        };
        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://nodeD2.test.webservices.amadeus.com");

        _client = new HotelAvailability_PTClient(binding, endpoint);

        List<HotelSearchCriteriaTypeCriterion> hotelSearchCriteriaTypeCriterias = new List<HotelSearchCriteriaTypeCriterion>();
        hotelSearchCriteriaTypeCriterias.Add(new HotelSearchCriteriaTypeCriterion()
        {
            Position = new ItemSearchCriterionTypePosition()
            {
                Latitude = latitude,
                Longitude = longitude
            }
        });
        List<AvailRequestSegmentsTypeAvailRequestSegment> availRequestSegmentsTypeAvailRequestSegments = new List<AvailRequestSegmentsTypeAvailRequestSegment>();
        availRequestSegmentsTypeAvailRequestSegments.Add(new AvailRequestSegmentsTypeAvailRequestSegment()
        {
            HotelSearchCriteria = new AvailRequestSegmentsTypeAvailRequestSegmentHotelSearchCriteria()
            {
                Criterion = hotelSearchCriteriaTypeCriterias.ToArray()
            }
        });
        OTA_HotelAvailRQAvailRequestSegments oTA_HotelAvailRQAvailRequestSegments = new OTA_HotelAvailRQAvailRequestSegments()
        {
            AvailRequestSegment = availRequestSegmentsTypeAvailRequestSegments.ToArray()
        };
        var request = new OTA_HotelAvailRQ()
        {
            AvailRequestSegments = oTA_HotelAvailRQAvailRequestSegments
        };
        _client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "XXXXX";
        _client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "XXXXXX";

        var response = await _client.Hotel_MultiSingleAvailabilityAsync(request);  
        var result = response.OTA_HotelAvailRS;

        return string.Empty;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exceptions (logging, re-throwing, etc.)
        throw new ApplicationException("Error in SOAP request", ex);
    }
}


The error message indicate there might be issue in the configuration with Amadeus. you could check the request, credential, permission. for more detail you could refer official document:https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs
